# Defect distribution equation explanation

Tags: tools, metrics, defect-tracking

I cannot figure out the logic behind the following formula:

```
Defect distribution= (Total number of defects / Functional Area) * Phase * Status
```

How can I multiply by phase and status? How would the result make sense if I did? What would the unit be then?

This formula is based on the Zephyr tool support:

http://www.getzephyr.com/resources/whitepapers/qa-metrics-value-testing-metrics-within-software-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree: that equation is confusing.  I think what they're trying to say is that the defect distribution is a set of four-tuples of the form `(functional area, test phase, bug status, total defects in that function area for that test phase and that bug status)`.

Now, imagine a table with those four columns.  You could take different slices through the data to infer things about your project and your test process.

Comment: I still somehow cannot see it :( If you read the text they provided, I just do not understand how they derive anything mentioned there.

Comment: The best way to find out what Zephyr meant by that is to [ask Zephyr](https://support.getzephyr.com/hc/en-us/community/topics).

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon for software engineering metrics to completely ignore the units on either side of the equation, lifting two fingers at the concept of [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis). The whitepaper describes the metric as

> Though somewhat simplistic, a basic way of looking at defect distribution

I would suggest you follow their advice there if you want to use their metric. There are other ways of tracking the spread of defects across a project lifecycle if you should prefer to use them.